# How to add grid to tab panel

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

How can i add grid in the center of the tab panel..My grid is not taking margins,`style:{margintop:'10px'}` even height: and width:

here is my grid:-

```
{
        title: 'Credit Card',
        id:'credit_tab',
        html:'html',
        items:[{ 
                    xtype:'grid',

                    title: 'Simpsons',
                    resizable: true,
                   // margins:'20 20 20 20',
                    style:{marginLeft:'200px',marginTop:'30px'},
                    //store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
                    columns: [
                        { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
                        { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
                        { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
                    ],
                  //  height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                  // renderTo:Ext.getBody()
                }]

         }
```

Comment: Use [`center`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Center) layout, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting the grid into a container.  Then from the container you can try out different sizes and layouts to place it exactly where you want.  Here's one example.

I would remove the "style" padding/position, at least to start and see how you like within the container.  Then pad/position from there. Try this:

```
 {
    title: 'Credit Card',
    id:'credit_tab',
    html:'html',
    items:[{
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'center',
                pack: 'center', 
            },

            items: [{ 
                    xtype:'grid',   
                    title: 'Simpsons',
                    resizable: true,
                   // margins:'20 20 20 20',
                    height: 200,
                    //store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
                    columns: [
                        { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
                        { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
                        { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
                    ],
                  //  height: 100,
                    width: 500, 
                  // renderTo:Ext.getBody()
                }]  
        }]

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use CSS positioning (margins etc.) for that purpose. Use [`layout: center`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Center).

Here is an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s7h